# Bind UIPickerView with key and value

Tags: uipickerview, ipad

I am working on UIPickerView. I am able to bind and get the selected value with the below code

```
pickerItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               [[[Company alloc] initWithName:@"Alabama" value:@"AL"] autorelease],
               [[[Company alloc] initWithName:@"Alaska" value:@"AK" ] autorelease],
               [[[Company alloc] initWithName:@"Arizona" value:@"AZ"] autorelease],
               [[[Company alloc] initWithName:@"California" value:@"CA"] autorelease],
               [[[Company alloc] initWithName:@"Wyoming" value:@"WY"] autorelease], nil];
```

but i am using a webservice from where i get the key and value. i want them to bind using a loop with key and value.

If i use the below code i am getting the exception 'Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"'

```
NSMutableArray *restArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Company %d ", i]; 
    NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Company %d ", i]; 
    Company *rest = [[Company alloc] initWithName:key value:val];
    NSLog(@"restArray=%@ (%@)", restArray, NSStringFromClass([restArray class]));
    [restArray addObject:rest];
    [rest release];
}
pickerItems = restArray;
[restArray release];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've assigned the pointer from 'restArray' to 'pickerItems', but you're releasing restArray immediately afterward.  So whatever pickerItems is pointing to has been released.  What are you doing with pickerItems after that point?